# L'emprunt « has(-)been » : accord au pluriel, trait d'union ?

Tags: anglais, accord, emprunts, trait-d-union

[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/has_been/39168) et [Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/has-been) en ligne donnent l'emprunt « [has-been](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/has-been) » (sans trait d'union) invariable (Robert mentionne de surcroît l’adjectif) tandis que [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/has-been) fait l'accord au pluriel (*has-beens*) pour le nom uniquement et présente l'orthographe sans le trait d'union comme une [variante](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/has_been) orthographique en locution nominale.

Qu'est-ce qui justifierait qu'il y ait accord au pluriel et trait d'union ou non et est-ce typique de ce genre d'emprunt ; qu'est-ce qui expliquerait cette « hésitation » ?

Answer (score 1):

**has-beens**
Les dictionnaire Anglais et US indiquent qu'en Anglais le pluriel de has-been est has-beens.

L'Académie française préconise, selon les recommandations de 1990 du Conseil supérieur de la langue française, que les mots étrangers prennent les marques du pluriel françaises (*Ex. des mangas, des scénarios, des bonzaïs, des geishas, des mousmées, des raviolis*) même si le mot est invariable dans sa langue d'origine.

**has-been**
Considérer has-been comme invariable relève de la formation usuelle du pluriel des noms composés qui pose souvent problème en Français : Pour s'y retrouver, il faut être attentif à la nature des mots qui composent le nom composé. D'une manière générale, noms et adjectifs ont tendance à s'accorder tandis que verbes, adverbes et prépositions sont invariables.